# Change ionic bundle identifier not working in IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I hade to create a new Ionic app since the first one stopped working.
After that It got new numbers in the end of the name (i.e old name com.ionicframework.test420004, new name com.ionicframework.test122446).
I changed it everywhere (search and replace in VisualStudio 2015) I could find in the project.
IOS still looks for local (downloaded) files with the path of the wrong application name.
Does anybody know how to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario you have to build it using cordova on a Apple computer. You can't build it and add the platform on a pc and the export the platform to an Apple computer.